# Access the Return value of a Stored procedure

Tags: javascript, sql-server, json, node.js

I am calling a stored procedure 'ujo_get_id' by following code

```
new sql.Request()
    .input('id', sql.Int, 0)
    .input('fld', sql.VarChar(10), fld)
    .execute('ujo_get_id').then(function( recordsets) {
        console.log(recordsets[0][0]);
    }.catch(function(err) {
        // ... execute error checks
    });
```

output of the console shows this `{ ' ': "some value" }` 
I want to store  that(some value) value in a variable how can I do it because key is empty

Comment: Are you able to modify the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the stored procedure has a select statement without an alias. If you can modify the stored procedure, add an alias and it shouldn't return an empty string for a key.

Something like this:

```
SELECT somefield
```

Should be changed to this:

```
SELECT somefield as someAliasName
```

If you don't have access to the stored procedure, try grabbing the key like this:

```
recordsets[0][0]['']
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
console.log(recordsets[0][0][" "])
```

Or maybe another way if you know for sure that the stored procedure will give you only one result is converting the object into an array and checking first element:

```
var raw = recordsets[0][0]
var result = Object.keys(raw).map(k => raw[k])[0]
console.log(result)
```